# Return inside if else and using fat arrow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, syntactic-sugar

Error when i try to return userInput inside conditional operator in fat-arrow function. Kindly advice.

Using **ES5** my code works fine;

```
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors' ) {
  return userInput;
} else {
  console.log('Error!');
}
console.log(getUserChoice('Paper')); // console prints 'paper'
console.log(getUserChoice('fork')); // console prints 'Error!' and `undefined`
```

**But** when I use **ES6** fat-arrow and conditional operator there is an error.
Note: I want to return the **userInput** immediately the first condition of if..else statement evaluates.

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors')? return userInput : console.log('Error');
};

console.log(getUserChoice('Paper'));
console.log(getUserChoice('fork'));
```

The **error** below appears:

```
  (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors')? return userInput : console.log('Error');
                                                                               ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
```

Comment: should have "return" in front of that line. Makes no sense in a ternary operator. And if you set up lint, the way you do it, it would complain that not all routes `return`

Comment: And perfect example of how the first syntax is both clearer and easier to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `return` at the beginning of the conditional statement like:

```
return (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors')? userInput : console.log('Error');
```

Comment: @WahinyaBrian glad to help

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create different branches in JavaScript:

1) The `if()` statement to branch *a statement or a block of statements*

```
 if(cond) {
   statement1;
   statement2;
 } else statement 3
```

2) The ternary operator which branches *expressions*.

```
 cond ? expression1 : expression2
```

`return` is a statement, and a statement can't be inside an expression. You either `return` the whole ternary or you use an `if`.

Ternaries were introduced a long time ago, this has nothing todo with the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to realize that `?:` is an **operator**. It is evaluated just like any other operator such as `+` and `*` to create a new value. With this in mind, you can understand why the placement of `return` doesn't make sense in your original version. `return` is a command (or more accurately a statement), not a value.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that at least helps me understand the logic behind placement of return